# Auto-Scaling Group Simple Policy CPU Utilization

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Does the AWS ASG Simple Policy for CPU Utilization trigger based on the aggregate sum measure or the maximum measure?

I am referring to the sum and max statistics listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Statistic.

**Example:**

Say I have an ASG policy to create a new instance when CPU usage exceeds 50%. I have a minimum of 2 instances and a maximum of 10 instances, and I currently have 2 instances. If the aggregate sum reaches above 50%, will I get a new instance? Or will the maximum need to exceed 50% too?

Answer (score 1):

I figured the answer out by setting up a simple policy for CPU usage on my ASG. I checked the CloudWatch alarm that triggers at the policy and it is based on **average**.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for providing an answer to your question, I was interested but couldn't find anything on the AWS site that answered it.